# Other than the intent, is there a difference in how you implement Chain of Responsibility and Decorator Pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented

I think it's fair to say that they are quite similar to each other.
The only difference that I know is the intent.

**Chain of Responsibility:** Avoid coupling between the sender of a request to its receiver by giving more than one object a chance to handle the request. Chain the receiving objects and pass the request along the chain until an object handles it. Not all objects may get chance or be able to handle the request.

**Decorator :** Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to sub-classing for extending functionality. All decorator objects handle the request by enhancing the data in their own way.

But is there a difference if implementation? Apart from the fact that in Chain of responsibility you could break the chain at any point?

The following is an example of Decorator Pattern. But if you had asked me to write an example of Chain of responsibility, I could have written the same example.

Yes, I could have also added the condition where I check if the request is to be forwarded further and then break the chain, if not. But is that a mandatory thing for it to qualify as a Chain of Responsibility Pattern?

If it's not then doesn't the following serves as an example of both Chain of Responsibility and Decorator pattern? Does chain of responsibility differ only by an extra if condition that check if  it is to be forwarded? Or is there more to it?

```
public interface IStream
{
    void write(string data);
}

public class CloudStream : IStream
{
    public void write(string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Writing to cloud storage..");
    }

}
public class EncryptStream : IStream
{
    private IStream stream { get; set; }

    public EncryptStream(IStream stream)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public void write(string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypting stream..");
        var encryptedData = Encrypt(data);
        this.stream.write(data);
    }

    private object Encrypt(string data)
    {
        return data; // return encrypted data
    }
}

public class CompressStream : IStream
{
    private IStream stream { get; set; }

    public CompressStream(IStream stream)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public void write(string data)
    {
        var compressedData = Compress(data);
        Console.WriteLine("Compressing stream..");
        this.stream.write(data);
    }

    private object Compress(string data)
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Wikipedia articles for [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) and [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) explain the differences quite well, including the differences in implementation.  I'm not sure what we could add here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey " .. many implementations (such as loggers below, or UI event handling, or servlet filters in Java, etc) allow several elements in the chain to take responsibility."

This is exactly why I am asking the question. I have found tons of examples by reputed authors/bloggers who gave examples for chain of responsibility where they  "allow several elements in the chain to take responsibility." 

I am no longer sure if "exactly one of the classes in the chain handles the request" is a mandatory for it to be called Chain of Responsibility.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know, I am probably splitting hairs at this point. But I need to know this for my mental peace.

Comment: What you just said.  The software patterns are already well-known for solving multiple problems and having overlap.  That's part of the reason they are useful.

Comment: Software development attracts people who like to be *precise.*  The problem, of course, is that only certain things about computers are precise.  There's no "right" way to write software, and if there is, just wait five minutes and it will change.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see your point. So I guess I won't be wrong if I used the same example for both the patterns. Technically speaking. I was worried that I am missing something significant that I am not able to see.

Comment: Using a precise definition of a software pattern when attempting to apply a software pattern to a problem isn't going to work.  Instead, evaluate the software pattern within the context of the specific problem you're trying to solve, and choose the pattern that is the best fit.  And, since the catalog of software patterns is not comprehensive, know when to write your own code.

Comment: Your code example doesn't seem like a good one for either pattern.  Look at the example code in the Wikipedia articles.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721256

Comment: I had already seen that stackoverflow link. That's how I know the difference in the intent. I think I am at peace now. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

> Yes, I could have also added the condition where I check if the request is to be forwarded further and then break the chain, if not. But is that a mandatory thing for it to qualify as a Chain of Responsibility Pattern?

Yes, according to GoF’s strict definition:

> if the ConcreteHandler can handle the request, it does so; otherwise it forwards the request to its successor.

> But is there a difference if implementation? Apart from the fact that in Chain of responsibility you could break the chain at any point?

Their class diagrams are also slightly different:

- Chain of responsability pattern:
  [image: Class diagram of the Chain of responsability pattern.]
- Decorator pattern:
  [image: Class diagram of the Decorator pattern.]

As you can see, the `successor` property of the Chain of responsability references the class itself, while the `component` property of the Decorator pattern references another class.